# Android Fragment, Force View to release manually

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I've a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and I switch between `ActionBarSherlock` Tabs. When switching between Tabs, I hide one `Fragment` and Display another `Fragment`.

Now I've a question about the memory consumation, how the `FragmentManager` Releases the `Fragments`, if I hide it?
When there are more `Fragments` in it, is it possible to manually remove a `Fragment Object` from memory?

if I detach a `Fragment`, the Object is saved, if I remove a `Fragment` it is only removed from the `View`, if I set the `Fragment = null`, then the `Fragment` is not released, I always get a Fragment: `myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);`

Can someone explain me how the `FragmentManager` releases the `Views`, if it is neccessary and how I can realize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) documentation.

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.

So if You are worried about memory issues don't use FragmentPagerAdapter, I would advice you to use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead.

> In FragmentStatePagerAdapter when pages are not visible to the user,
>   their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state
>   of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory
>   associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter
>   at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

FragmentStatePagerAdapter works somewhat like a listview and is more efficient in terms of memory.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think on Fragments there are some changes necessary. I realized there are only dirty workarounds (except the Viewpager Solution, but what always preload the next Tab). When using tabs I save the view State and recreate the View state based upon Variables.